# Writing to Text files via php

Tags: php, io

I have a little issue while trying to kill time. I am  writint to a text file the contents of the filled in form so it is easy to read. At the moment everything gets put int a single line, and therfore I can not tell where  msgs begin or end. I wrote a php like this:

```
$from = $_POST[from];
$friend = $_POST[friend];
$carrier = $_POST[carrier];
$message = stripslashes($_POST[message]);

if ((empty($from)) || (empty($friend)) || (empty($message))) {
header ("Location: sms_error.php");
}

else if ($carrier == "orange_mobile_network") {
$formatted_number = $friend."@orange_mobile_network.co.uk";
mail("$formatted_number", "SMS", "$message"); 

header ("Location: sms_success.php");
}
```

Then the SMS/Text message will be sent. After this I wanted to  write/store/append the message on a txt file. So I wrote:

```
$myFile = "sms_Numbers_Mgs.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a+') or die("can't open file");

$stringData = $_POST[from];
fwrite($fh, $stringData);

$stringData = $_POST[friend];
fwrite($fh, $stringData);

$stringData = $_POST[message];
fwrite($fh, $stringData);

fclose($fh);
```

But like I said. Everything works. I just want to be able to read the file and put everything in a new line and possibly format it nicely for easy reading. I do not want to use a DB for storing the TXT as my host is going to charge me.

Comment: I recommend you enclosing array indices in single quotes.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [SQLite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php) as a database solution that uses a file for the database in the same manner you are using.  I can't say for sure, but your host probably wouldn't charge you to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
```

with this:

```
fwrite($fh, $stringData . PHP_EOL);
```

or:

```
fwrite($fh, $stringData . "\r\n");
```

Comment: +1 @JellyBelly the last part of your code worked for me thank you so much !!

Answer (score 0):

You can append `PHP_EOL` when you write for a platform aware newline. I.e. `$stringData = <string> . PHP_EOL;`

If don't need it to be platform aware, going with the windows newline is a safe option.

```
define('CRLF', "\r\n");

$stringData = <string> . CRLF;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly Cause you're using. txt instead of a bank, but my tip for this specific case is to work with json format.

Example:

```
$myFile = "sms_Numbers_Mgs.txt";

$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a+') or die("can't open file");

//assembles a string of type json
$data = json_encode(array(
    'from'    => $_POST[from],
    'friend'  => $_POST[friend],
    'message' => $_POST[message]
));

//Write in the file
fwrite($fh, $data);
fclose($fh);

//reads the file
$content = file_get_contents($myFile);
$object  = json_decode($content);
var_dump($object);
```

good it is at least better organized.

a hug!

Comment: Thank u for the reply. I tried your solution it works fine just like mine. But It still put it in one line. every time I run the script.